# HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway

Tags: perl, iis, error-handling, iis-7.5

I am trying to learn Perl so I need to be able to test it locally.  I have `IIS7.5` and I have the `pl` and `cgi` mapped.  But I am throwing this error when I test it in Chrome.

It works fine when I use the command prompt. So I don't understand what I am missing or how to troubleshoot this.  I've searched all over google, can someone help me.

*My test code:*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;

my $test = new CGI();

print $test->header("text/html"),$test->start_html("PERL Test");
print $test->h1("PERL IS WORKING!");
print $test->end_html;
```

[image: Browser Screen Shot]

And the command console spits out a perfectly programmed HTML page:
[image]

Comment: Stop! It's 2016. Please don't write web applications using CGI (or CGI.pm). Perl has perfectly good modern tools for writing web applications. Look at PSGI and Plack.